# How to use SVOX pico TTS with Libreoffice 7.1 flatpak?

Tags: libreoffice, text-to-speech

What I have done:

1. I have installed pico:

   `sudo apt-get install libttspico0 libttspico-utils libttspico-data`
2. I have installed the read text extension from [here](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/read-text)
3. I have tried to configure the read text extension by entering

   /usr/bin/python3

in the external program field

and
"(PICO_READ_TEXT_PY)" --language=(SELECTION_LANGUAGE_COUNTRY_CODE) "(TMP)"

in the command line options field.

I use the flatpak version of libreoffice on Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of the program might use a different version of python or specify different paths to files than the normal LibreOffice installation does.

You could try:

```
    "(SPD_READ_TEXT_PY)" --language "(SELECTION_LANGUAGE_CODE)" "(TMP)"
```

in the command lines field to see if the extension works with `speech-dispatcher`, the speech daemon that powers the [Orca](https://help.gnome.org/users/orca/stable/introduction.html.en) screen reader.

The default speech settings for Orca might be too verbose for casual users, but if you want to try Orca with LibreOffice, open a Terminal and type:

```
    orca -s
```

If you start `orca` from the command line, you can instantly disable it by closing the terminal window, otherwise, you need to learn the keyboard shortcuts applicable to your system.

You asked the question a while ago, so check to see if the newest version of the extension solves your problem.

Comment: This is not an answer it is a comment. Answers do not have terms like You could try.